# How to load this class in the correct way?

Tags: java, classloader, noclassdeffounderror, bytecode, byte-buddy

Alright, so I have a class

```
class A{
    public D d = new B$0();

    public void foo(){
        B$0 b;
        try{
            b = (B$0)this.d;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
             this.d = d.move(this); //actual implementation uses a CAS to make sure it's only replaced once
             throw new RepeatThisMethodException();
        }
        //do something with b here
    }
}
```

Where `RepeatThisMethodException` is handled by some code further up.

```
abstract class D{
    public abstract D move(Object o);
}
```

and

```
class B$0 extends D{
    public static D moveThis(A a){
        throw new Error();
    }

    public D move(Object o){
        return moveThis((A)o);
    }|
}
```

I now create a new class

```
class B$1 extends D{
    public D move(Object o){
        return B$0.moveThis((A)o);
    }
}
```

And load it using ByteBuddy.

```
    DynamicType.Builder builder = byteBuddy
            .subclass(D.class)
            .name("B$1")
            ;

    DynamicType.Unloaded newClass = builder.make();
    byte[] rawBytecode = newClass.getBytes();
    byte[] finishedBytecode = MyASMVisitor.addMethods(rawBytecode);

    Class b0 = Class.forName("B$0");
    ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION.load(b0.getClassLoader(),
            Collections.singletonMap(newClass.getTypeDescription(), finishedBytecode));
```

(Note that I'm using `B$0.class.getClassloader()` to load `B$1`.)

The bytecode for that `move` method `MyASMVisitor` adds looks like this:

```
public Method move:"(Ljava/lang/Object;)LD;"
    stack 1 locals 2
{
        aload_1;
        checkcast   class A;
        invokestatic    Method B$0.moveThis:"(LA;)LD;";
        areturn;
}
```

Now that `B$1` is loaded, I re-instrument `B$0` s.t. it can handle the new class.

```
class B$0 extends D{
    public static D moveThis(A a){
        if(a.d instanceof B$1) throw new RepeatThisMethodException();
        if(a.d instanceof B$0) return new B$1();
        throw new Error();
    }

    public D move(Object o){
        return moveThis((A)o);
    }|
}
```

and reload it using

```
private void redefineClass(String classname, byte[] bytecode) {
    Class clazz;
    try{
        clazz = Class.forName(classname);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    ClassReloadingStrategy s = ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent();
    s.load(clazz.getClassLoader(),
            Collections.singletonMap((TypeDescription)new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(clazz), bytecode));
}
```

So `B$0` gets reloaded by `B$0.class.getClassLoader()`.

Now that `B$1` exists and can be handled, I let `A` know it should use the new class from now on.

```
class A{
    public D d = new B$1();

    public void foo(){
        B$1 b;
        try{
            b = (B$1)this.d;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
             this.d = d.move(this); //actual implementation uses a CAS to make sure it's only replaced once
             throw new RepeatThisMethodException();
        }
        //do something with b here
    }
}
```

And reload it using the same `redefineClass` method (so `A` gets reloaded by `A.class.getClassLoader()`).

In effect, new instances of `A` will use `B$1` right from the get-go, while existing instances will call `b.move(this)`, which in turn will call `B$0.moveThis((A)o)` (where it cannot use `this`.

This seems to work, for now.

The problem now is that we need to update ALL classes that ever use a version of `B` obviously, we cannot reload them all simultaneously, so some are going to be earlier and some are going to be late.

Let's say we have a class `G` that uses `A a` and consequently, its `a.d`.

`A` is already reloaded, `G` isn't yet. So some methods on `A` (or any other already reloaded client of `A`) may have triggered the `move` already while `G` still tries to cast to `B$0`.

That's fine.

If `G` uses `A a` and fails to cast `a.d` to the version it expects, it will call `a.d.move(a)` which in turn calls `B$0.moveThis((A)a)`.

In that case,

```
if(a.d instanceof B$1) throw new RepeatThisMethodException();
```

in our handling code in `B$0` ensures that `G` cannot make progress until its bytecode has been reloaded and it knows about `B$1`.

Or it *WOULD*, if `B$1` would be able to call `B$0.moveThis`.

Instead, we get

```
Exception in thread "MyT1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A
    at B$1.move(Unknown Source)
```

Alright, that is unfortunate. Let's see if we can circumvent this error by moving the cast of `Object o` to `B$0.moveThis` ...

```
Exception in thread "MyT1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: B$0
    at B$1.move(Unknown Source)
```

Nope, doesn't look like.

How do I load `B$1` s.t. it has access to at least `B$0` and both `B$0` and `A` (and whatever clients of `A`, eventually) have access to it?

**Note**

Any kind of solution needs to support upcasting.

E.g. say I have `D :> B :> C` and we use `B b = new C()` (or pass an instance of `C` to a method expecting a `B` or ...), then `b.move(b)` must still call `C$0.moveThis((C)b)`.

**Update** (Thanks, Holger)

The issues seems unrelated to the redefinition of existing classes.

```
    Class b0 = Class.forName("B$0");
    ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION.load(b0.getClassLoader(),
            Collections.singletonMap(newClass.getTypeDescription(), finishedBytecode));

    try {
        Class c = Class.forName("B$1");
        Object instance = c.newInstance();
        c.getMethod("move", Object.class).invoke(instance, new Object());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

which calls `B$1.move()` before any other class has been reloaded, is in fact enough to trigger the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

**Update**

When I print `clazz.getClassLoader()` for reloading classes and `b0.getClassLoader()` for new classes, I always get the same instance of `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`.

Comment: “we cannot reload them all simultaneously”—why not? It is your code which explicitly uses `Collections.singletonMap(…)` where the API accepts arbitrary `Map`s.

Comment: @Holger Wouldn't I also need to somehow specify which classloaders they should use? (reload ``A`` using ``A.class.getClassLoader()``, ``B`` using ``B.class.getClassLoader()``, ...) Or can I just use any arbitrary classloader in this use case?

Comment: For retransformation with an Agent, the class loader argument does not matter for already loaded classes, as those already have a defining loader that will never change. Only if your map also contains type descriptions of unresolved types, the method will try to resolve them through the specified class loader.

Comment: @Holger I'm afraid that didn't work out. Same error.

Comment: It seems that your problem isn’t even connected to the redefinition. Just try to invoke the `move` method via Reflection after `B$1` has been loaded (before even attempting to redefine the other classes). Does it work then or is it already showing the same problems regarding resolving `A` or `B$0`?

Comment: @Holger you're right, I'm already getting a ``NoClassDefFoundError: B$0`` there. What does that mean? Or more importantly, how do I resolve it?

Comment: I don’t know. It seems that it can find `D` as otherwise, it would fail even earlier. But given that you provide `b0.getClassLoader()` as context, it’s strange that it can’t find `B$0`. Though, I’m a bit surprised about the `Class.forName("B$0")` and `Class.forName("B$1")` calls (without a class loader argument). That implies that you are manipulating your own class loader, as those expressions are not different to `B$0.class` resp. `B$1.class` regarding the class loading context.

Comment: @Holger Could you elaborate on that point? The reason I'm using ``Class.forName`` instead of ``.class`` is simply that I don't have all classes at compile time and need to handle multiple different classes in this way. What do you mean by "my own class loader"?

Comment: [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) uses the caller’s defining class loader. In your case, that should be the same class loader used to, e.g. resolve `D.class`. It would be interesting, if there are any differences between the defining loaders of your classes

Comment: @Holger When I print ``clazz.getClassLoader()`` for reloading classes and ``b0.getClassLoader()`` for new classes, I always get the same instance ``sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6da21389``.

Comment: Hmm. There might be some important piece missing, but I don’t know which question to ask. There is only one suggestion, I can make: try the whole thing on Java 9; it produces better exception messages, e.g. when resolving a class failed due to another failure on one of its dependencies. Or well, there’s one more question: do you actually use `A` anywhere in that context before the failure? Or, in other words, did you check whether `A` is available at all?

Comment: @Hogler Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot use Java 9 because the framework I'm working with requires Java 7. -.- But yes, both ``A`` and ``B$0`` get loaded and used. (Besides, if the classes really weren't available yet, wouldn't the whole thing (a) fail much earlier or (b) load the classes when I use ``Class.forName("B$0")`` ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem in the actual code generation as discussed in the [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/419#issuecomment-373919627).